Disable script caching in Passenger / mod_passenger?
My web host supports Phusion Passenger in Apache via mod_passenger; I'm using it to trial some basic Python WSGI scripts. During development, is there some way I can just tell Passenger (or mod_passenger) to disable script caching entirely, versus having to do a passenger-config restart-app . every time a script changes?
The host is using Passenger 6.0.19 + Apache 2.4.58 + Ubuntu 20.04.1 - in case the versions make a difference.
